# How do I validate and decipher Authorization Bearer Token obtained from Azure AD in a Node Azure Function (for Role Based Access Control)?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, bearer-token, rbac

I'm using Azure AD and have registered an application in it. I've used [msal-browser JS library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser) to sign-in the user and obtain an Authorization token:

```js
{
    //...
    "accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkY...",
    "account": {
        "homeAccountId": "00000000-0000-0000-bac6-4831a1177397.9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad",
        "environment": "login.windows.net",
        "tenantId": "62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424",
        "username": "tfgh55555@outlook.com",
        "localAccountId": "6fad727e-1df2-4b14-b234-30b407b7ab42",
        "name": "Tali Gehrin",
        "idTokenClaims": {
            "aud": "0d42647a-183c-404b-bbe1-796ad6420989",
            "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424/v2.0",
            "iat": 1633271767,
            "nbf": 1633271767,
            "exp": 1633275667,
            "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/",
            "name": "Tali Gehrin",
            "nonce": "b04400da-eb58-4617-bbaa-5c66e04d762a",
            "oid": "6fad727e-1df2-4b14-b234-30b407b7ab42",
            "preferred_username": "tfgh55555@outlook.com",
            "rh": "0.AREAFVd2YoEgUEC9x4wuF410JHpkQg08GEtAu-F5atZCCYkRABI.",
            "roles": [
                "content_manager" //<= the role i'm interested in
            ],
            "sub": "WbvYLdLb3DNVgczM_iyu4n4i-s8mPtfhQqVyAK_abaU",
            "tid": "62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424",
            "uti": "HDhn_MWkl0iGcm-jlBEMAA",
            "ver": "2.0"
        }
    },
    //...
}
```

I'm passing `accessToken` in an HTTP call as header

```
Authorization: Bearer yJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkY...
```

How do I validate and decipher this token inside an Azure function running Node?

Answer (score -2):

You can validate and decipher this token inside an [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/azure-functions?tutorial-step=1) running Node by Azure function that implements the HTTP trigger. This requires configuration data to perform a token validation and these are inside the AzureAdTokenAttribute instance. However, the token will be inside the HttpRequest. To have access to what was implemented in the token validation service, you will insert IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: From what I can see, Azure Function part of the example is C#, not JS?

Comment: Several versions of the Azure function runtime are available.
Yes, JavaScript is also supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages#languages-by-runtime-version

Comment: Is there an example of getting roles from Bearer Token in JS Azure Function specifically? Or maybe configuring function runtime to do it and provide deciphered token with function arguments?

Comment: You need to follow this doc for Azure Function JavaScript : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2